# React Native Share Extension won't build

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, macros, linker

I'm trying to add a Share Extension to a React Native app and when I try to build the app I get this linking error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_RCTRegisterModule", referenced from:
      _initialize_ShareManager in ShareManager-75b70a88150f3f544e5598c2fcbaaa49e4e22b3f47bce8d9a721bf31763b426d.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

This is the offending code (when I comment this out the rest of the app builds fine):

```
@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(ShareManager, NSObject)

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(getURL: (RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback)

@end
```

Has anyone got any insight into how I can fix this? I've done a lot of googling and tried a hundred different permutations of linking binaries, different linker flags etc. But so far I've got nowhere.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Which version of react native and xcode are you using?

Comment: @Kaushik I'm using react native 0.61.2 and the xcode beta 11.2

Comment: Did you try auto linking (pod install), in case you ran `react-native link` ? Did you add `javaScriptCore.framework` in `Link Binary With Libraries `?

Comment: I have linked javaScriptCore.framework but still getting error